# Angular5 enter/leave animation has no effect

Tags: angular, css-animations, angular-animations

I followed the tutorial found at https://angular.io/guide/animations but can't replicate the effect.

My template (html) contains:

```
<div *ngFor='let message of messages' [@slideInOut]="'in'" class="message">
   ...
</div>
```

and my message class has a height attribute:

```
div.message {
   height: 26px;
}
```

I would like the messagesto slide in and out (Y-axis) when they are added/removed from the messages list. The following animation trigger doesn't do anything, and it doesn't give any errors. what am I missing?

```
 animations: [
    trigger('slideInOut', [
      state('in', style({height: '*'})),
      transition('void => *', [
        style({height: '0px'}),
        animate(1000)
      ]),
      transition('* => void', [
        animate(1000), style({height: '0px'})])
    ])
  ]
```

I was thinking that maybe, when removing elements from the DOM, the animation will never work because the element is gone before the animation can play. But even if that is the case, it should still do something for when an element is added to the list right?

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the `:enter` and `:leave` transition keywords. The animation will be triggered when the elements are added and removed from the DOM.

**animations**

```
animations: [
  trigger('slideInOut', [
    transition(:enter ', [
      style({
        height: '0px'
      }),
      animate(1000, style({
        height: '*'
      })]),
    transition(':leave', [
      animate(1000), style({
        height: '0px'
      })
    ])
  ])
]
```

**component.html**

```
<div *ngFor='let message of messages' @slideInOut class="message">
  ...
</div>
```

Check out the [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/animations#example-entering-and-leaving) on the subject.

Comment: I already know that tutorial, I link to the same thing in my question. The keywords change no behaviour. It doesn't work, but I don't egt any compile or runtime errors so what could I missing?